# Handling input confirmations in Linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, apt, debconf

I'm writing a Linux Shell Script to automate a few things I'm doing on Ubuntu 11.04.

Basically, I'm writing a shell script to install NGINX, MySQL, and PHP, and then configure everything. I know how to do everything via the command-line.

However, I don't know how I'm going to handle the parts where the process asks for user input. For example, certain things I install with apt-get ask you for a confirmation i.e. (Y)es or (N)o.

How exactly would I handle auto-confirmation in the shell script i.e. to automatically confirm Yes or No when asked?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script  (hope it helps!)

Comment: @heltonbiker: I'm not trying to get input from the user of the shell script, I'm trying to force/make input wherever my script would usually have prompted me to provide a Yes or No response.

Comment: Your're right, I read it wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`yes | ./script` will answer  `y` for everything.

Otherwise, write a script that prints the answers you want, eg:

```
 echo N
 echo Y
 echo Y
```

Comment: Thanks for this option. I'm not sure how exactly I would structure the script to do this though, do you have a code sample?

Comment: If you don't want to answer always 'yes', I don't really get your question, since it's completely case-dependant. If you want to answer "yes yes no" to a script, simply: `printf "y\ny\nn\n" | ./your_script` or write a simple script with seperate lines to print each answer, and then: `./answer_script | ./the_script`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I have multiple options now just in case I want to answer differently to different prompts. This appears to be the most elegant way to do what I want to do being that I only need to call it once with the script.

Comment: What would you echo if the prompt asks you for a non-character keystroke e.g. "press enter to continue"?

Answer (score 3):

Usually you can call such interactive programs with an option to automatically answer yes to all questions. For instance, you can call `apt-get` with `-y`. From the man page :

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>              Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run
>              non-interactively.

Answer (score 2):

For Apt, the correct answer is to "preseed" your `debconf` database with the correct parameters. If Debconf finds the answer from its database, it won't ask. See also http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/394

Comment: The link is now quite out of date. More recent documentation exists at e.g. https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed and in [Appendix B of the Debian Installer manual](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apb) but these are not particularly beginner-friendly. https://thornelabs.net/posts/debian-ubuntu-preseed-documentation-and-working-examples.html looks more approachable, but also somewhat prone to future link rot.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it looks very interesting. Would I have to know exactly what the prompt is going to be i.e. if the command I run in my shell script is going to do something like "Enter your date of birth:", would I have to write Expect "Enter your date of birth:" exactly as the prompt is going to ask for it?!