# exim4-config script automated?

Tags: bash, exim, exim4

I need to setup exim4 on multiple servers however I was wondering if it's possible to create a script that will automatically go through the install process and set it up on exim4 with my hostname?

sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config

Step 1 : Top option (Internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP

Step 2 : hostname  (default)

Step 3 : 127.0.0.1 ; ::1 (default)

Step 4 : hostname  (default)

Step 5 : hostname

step 6 : hostname

step 7 : No

Step 8 : mbox format in /var/mail/

Step 9 : no

step 10 : root hostname

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling input confirmations in Linux shell scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410771/handling-input-confirmations-in-linux-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 5):

when I had this problem I did it like this using debconf-set-selections

```
debconf-set-selections <<CONF
exim4-config    exim4/dc_other_hostnames        string  $hostnames
exim4-config    exim4/dc_eximconfig_configtype  select  internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP
exim4-config    exim4/no_config boolean true
# rest of the secret sauce omitted...
CONF
```

Comment: Use `debconf-get-selections | grep exim4` on a system where exim4 is already installed to get a list of such settings. If you're missing the `debconf-get-selections` executable, you have to install `debconf-utils`.

Comment: This doesn't work on my Ubuntu server with Exim4 v4.92. For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61518823/198219

Answer (score 4):

The proper solution for Debian is to populate the Debconf database with your choices before running `dpkg-reconfigure`.  Read [`man debconf-set-selections`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/debconf-set-selections.1.html) for details.  There is a howto at https://www.debian-administration.org/article/394/Automating_new_Debian_installations_with_preseeding

Comment: It's worth noting the two comments from the link above which relate specifically to Exim... `Problems preseeding exim where probably due to the fact that debconf gets it's answers from '/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf' (something like this also happens in 'locales'). In a script I'm using, I first replace the original 'update-exim4.conf.conf' before updating/installing the packages.` & `The preseed method isn't perfect. I had lots of trouble preseeding exim and eventually I replaced exim with postfix.`

Answer (score 3):

You need to create `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` with your local values and then install Exim4 non-interactively, as suggested by @Dogsbody:

```sh
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get install -y exim4-daemon-light
```

If you already have Exim4 installed, you need to edit the config file and then execute the following, as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/615148/39337):

```sh
dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive exim4-config
```