# Automate exim4 setup?

Tags: installation, exim, exim4

I am trying to automate `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`

What's the easiest way?

Right now I am downloading a file and placing it into `cd /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`

http://pastebin.com/LtQ7fVfX

and I run it, but it comes back with the following error:

> root@domain:/etc/exim4# dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config : not
>   foundkg/info/exim4-config.config: 18:
>   /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf:

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I went with using `debconf-set-selections` rather than writing files directly

Comment: possible duplicate of [exim4-config script automated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054568/exim4-config-script-automated)

Comment: Yes, it's even the same person who posted.