# Automating *just* exim4 configuration with debconf-set-selections with Ansible

Tags: debian, ansible, configuration-files, exim4

I'm attempting to automate exim4 configuration on Debian in Ansible -- we have been manually configuring up until this point -- but I'm stuck at the stage where I'd run normally `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`.

I can automate these steps easily enough:

- Update the conf file at `/etc/exim4/exim4-config.conf.conf`
- Run `dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive exim4-config`

They run fine in the playbook, however the issue is that not all the options that I see in the interactive prompt are in this conf file. For example, the second setting, `System mail name` is not specified anywhere in the conf file. Nor is the last setting, `Root and postmaster mail recipient`, which also stops showing up in the interactive prompt after the first configuration (why is that?)

I then saw that some people have suggested using `debconf-set-selections` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054568/exim4-config-script-automated)), and I tried looking into that - I installed the `debconf-utils` package and then ran `debconf-get-selections` - I then saw all the options there, but now I'm wondering if there is a way to use `debconf-set-selections` without having to use a file that sets *all* of the settings all at once, since I just want to change the values associated with exim4. I'm trying to avoid overwriting any other values (not associated with exim4) that might be set if I need to run the playbook again.

Short of writing the output of `debconf-get-selections` to a file and then using Ansible's `lineinfile`/`template` modules to replace the values I want to change, is there perhaps a simpler way of going about this? I'd prefer to avoid this method.

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit late, but I suggest you to use the ansible [debconf module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debconf_module.html) (it basically does a `debconf-set-selections`).

Like this example :

```
- name: Debconf question dc_eximconfig_configtype
  debconf: name='exim4-config'
    question: 'exim4/dc_eximconfig_configtype'
    value: 'internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP'
    vtype: select
```

Or this one :

```
- name: Debconf question mailname
  debconf: name='exim4-config'
    question: 'exim4/mailname'
    value: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    vtype: string
```

However, if you are *reconfiguring* exim (after you configured it once), then you have to delete 2 files before doing a `dpkg-reconfigure`, it can be done with theses commands :

```
- name: remove exim config files
  file: path={{ item }} state=absent
  with_items:
    - "/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf"
    - "/etc/mailname"
```

Finally, do a `dpkg-reconfigure`, which also restart exim.

```
- name: Reconfigure package exim4-config
  command: dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive exim4-config
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the following error with the lines "debconf: name='exim4-config'":

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
```

and i also prefered to use "value: 'smarthost'" to set "dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'" in /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf...

Consequently, my roles/smtp_client/tasks/main.yml file contains the following lines:

```
- name: remove exim config files
  file: path={{ item }} state=absent
  with_items:
    - "/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf"
    - "/etc/mailname"

- name: Debconf question mailname
  debconf:
    name: 'ansible_hostname exim4-config'
    question: 'exim4/mailname'
    value: '{{ ansible_hostname }}'
    vtype: string

- name: Debconf question dc_eximconfig_configtype
  debconf:
    name: 'dc_eximconfig_configtype exim4-config'
    question: 'exim4/dc_eximconfig_configtype'
    value: 'smarthost'
    vtype: select

- name: Debconf question dc_smarthost
  debconf:
    name: 'dc_smarthost exim4-config'
    question: 'exim4/dc_smarthost'
    value: '{{ my_smtp_server }}'
    vtype: string

- name: Reconfigure package exim4-config
  command: dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive exim4-config
```