# BASH: How to ask user input and store it for the future?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to store a user message in a bash program, and then display the message the next time the user runs the script.

One way I thought this might work is if I export the message to an environmental variable, but I cannot get it to work.

Here is what I have so far, but it is not working:

```
echo "Last message was: $KEEPTHISMESSAGE"
echo "Type the new message that you want to enter, followed by [ENTER]:"
read KEEPTHISMESSAGE
export KEEPTHISMESSAGE
```

What am I doing wrong? If there is a better way to do this, please let me know. Maybe keep a file that keeps a history of these message and gets the most recent?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use EXPORT this way.  It only exports to processes started from within that invocation of the script.  You must store the message in a file on the filesystem and load it in the next time your user executes the script.  Very simply:

```
echo "Last message was: $(cat message.txt)"
echo "Type the new message that you want to enter, followed by [ENTER]:"
read KEEPTHISMESSAGE
echo $KEEPTHISMESSAGE > message.txt
```

You'll have to work out what happens the first time (when message.txt doesn't exist), and issues with relative/absolute paths to `message.txt` if you're running the script in a different directory.

Comment: +1 This can be modified to use a hidden file (starts with a . ) Call it ~/.yourprog.history Read this file in your bash script by sourcing it, and overwrite the contents when your script ends.

Comment: echo $KEEPTHISMESSAGE > message.txt  **overwrites or creates message.txt** ; Use  >> for append

Comment: @Paul but appending is undesirable in his question, if he does that he should use `tail -1` instead of `cat`

Comment: @Jim and everyone else, thanks this was the solution. i also used >> for appending, and tail -1 instead of cat

Comment: @Eric I was mostly concerned with resolving an issue "You'll have to work out what happens the first time when message.txt doesn't exist" in this answer.

Comment: '$ read -p "Type the new message that you want to enter, followed by [ENTER]:" KEEPTHISMESSAGE ' will do it in one step.

Answer (score 2):

Scripts can only directly export variables to their sub-processes. They can't export to parent processes.

You can alter a parents environment by invoking your script like this:

```
$ . /path/to/your_script.sh
```

Here your script should have an export statement to export the variable and must not have an exit statement.