# Echo text that is user-editable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Is it possible to output text to a shell window, via bash script, that is user-editable? I essentially want to pre-fill certain information and give the user the ability to edit it if it's wrong.

For instance, if I were to write in a script:

```
echo -n "Enter your name: Anthony"

while read user_input
do
    # do stuff with $user_input
done
```

How can I allow the user to inline edit the word `Anthony` *only* (aka, don't allow backspacing past the `A` in `Anthony`), and how can I store the value into a variable once the <kbd>RETURN</kbd> key is pressed?

***EDIT***

I'm looking for something similar to the `-i` option of `read` ([see answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5987314/969967)), but this is only available on bash 4+. Is there an alternative for bash 3?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script?

Comment: @emallove Not quite - I know how to read user input. The essence of what I'm trying to uncover is how to echo text that can be edited inline by the user.

Comment: Actually, I think I see what you're referring to. The answer by xaccrocheur seems to be what I'm looking for. Can something similar to this be done on bash 3.2.x?

Comment: If you want a feature that was added to Bash 4.x, then you have to upgrade to get it — or retrofit it into your own variant of Bash 3.x.  No; it isn't going to be available in Bash 3.x.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know _it_ won't be available in 3.x - I was inquiring about an alternative. But thank you for your input.

Comment: In theory you could provide an alternative to `read` that could be used like: `user_input=$(alt_read -i "$initial" -p "$prompt")` or thereabouts, and it would use the GNU `readline` library to display the prompt and initial data and echo the final information (as edited) to its standard output so that the shell captures it.  It wouldn't be all that dreadfully hard to write, but I don't know of anyone who's written it.  If you're sensible, you'll model the alternative on the `bash` 4.x `read` command notation (or a subset thereof), so it is as easy as possible to migrate.

Comment: Could [NCurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) help?

Comment: What about something like `dialog --no-lines --inputbox 'Enter your name:' 8 50 'Anthony'`?

Comment: on bash 4, `read` with `-i` only works with `-e`. My guess is that u have upgraded it already :>. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115308/235896

Answer (score 1):

I needed similar setup recently so what I did was

```
$ cat a.sh
function input {
  python -c '
import sys,readline
readline.set_startup_hook(lambda: readline.insert_text(sys.argv[2]))
sys.stderr.write(raw_input(sys.argv[1]))
' "$@" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
}

A=$( input 'question: ' default )
echo "A='$A'"

$ ./a.sh
question: default
A='default'
```

Well, it's not actually bash, but it made the job done.