# Linux bash shell script prompt user input and store in variable

Tags: bash, variables, user-input

How do I collect user input and store in variables to use in parameters for jar file execution?

Tried using read -p and bash's select command from following link but get errors: [How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script#) 
here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello "$USER"."
echo "Enter System :"
read name
echo "Enter Format (JPG/PDF):"
read format 

java -jar ~/folder/myjar.jar -input ~/scripts/file -output$format ~/output/$name.$format
```

This partially works in that it produces output file but the name variable is lost, format variable is generated in string ok.  Running this also generates the following errors: ": command not found" under hello user, " ': not a valid identifierame" after entering system name

Comment: Is that "fi" without an if statement in your original script or did you just forget to delete it when you copied it here? Otherwise I don't see any problems with your user input stuff. (That first prompt might be better written as `"Hello $USER."` though.)

Comment: that "fi" should not be there, forgot to delete. I should also add that the jar executable string is the command line for ksar output.

Comment: Can you execute your script with the verbose flag so we can see what it is doing?  --> "bash -x myscript.sh"

Comment: + $'\r'
: command not found
' echo 'Hello michael.
Hello michael.
+ $'\r'
: command not found
' echo 'Enter System:
Enter System:
+ read $'name\r'

': not a valid identifiername
' echo 'Enter Format (JPG/PDF):
Enter Format (JPG/PDF):
+ read format $'\r'

': not a valid identifier
+ $'\r'
: command not found
+ java -jar /home/michael/sar/myjar.jar -input /home/michael/scripts/file -output $'/home/michael/output//.\r'
time to parse: 2207ms number of line: 52381 line/msec: 23.0
+ $'\r'
: command not found
+ $'\r'
: command not found

Comment: @michael, those error messages mean that the error has nothing to do with prompting, and everything to do with your script being saved as a DOS-format text file, not a UNIX-format one.

Comment: Prompting the user and reading data is a *horrible* interface.  It is far better to take the parameters as arguments.  Imagine if `grep` worked this way, and prompted the user to enter the pattern to search for and the list of files in which to search.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have carriage return / windows line terminations, try to run

```
dos2unix input.txt
```

or

```
sed 's/^M$//' input.txt > output.txt
```

or

```
tr -d '\r' < input.txt > output.txt
```