# Shell Script: Issue in prompting for user input

Tags: shell, sh

I am asking this regarding the answer in "[How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)".

The code:

```
state="CA"
city="Los Angeles"
while true; do
    read -e -p "State: " -i $state state
    read -e -p "City: " -i $city city
    echo "Your state: $state"
    echo "Your city: $city"
done
```

This is how it runs.

```
$ ./test.sh
State: CA
City: Los
Your state: CA
Your city: 
State: DE
City: city
Your state: DE
Your city:
```

1st input: city not shown up correctly

1st output: I didn't type city, so it should show "Los", right?

2nd input: state changed to "DE", works good which means the shell supports that

but city defaults to "city", again I didn't type

2nd output: city not correct

Anyway, I think the problem is the space in "Los Angeles". How to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Extra Info

This is the bash that I am using.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Answer Found

Should use quote in -i, like

```
read -e -p "City: " -i "$city" city
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your belief about the problem is correct; and you have the info about how to fix it right there in front of you....

```
read -e -p "City: " -i "$city" city
```

Answer (score 4):

```
read -e -p "City: " -i $city city
```

`$city` has spaces so -i is `'Los'` instead of `'Angeles'`

So `Angeles` will be the variable set by `read`

Comment: If you don't believe try adding `echo "Angeles: $Angeles"`, it will print `Angeles: Los`