# User-Interactive,Shell Scripting

Tags: shell

I want to make my script user interactive. On running the script (./versionControl.sh) the first thing that should appear on the screen is

```
Please enter the package name::
```

When the user enters the package name it should take that package name as input and do further operations

How can i achieve this? Kindly help

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the BASH `read` command, like so:

```
echo "Enter your name, followed by [ENTER]:"
read name
echo $name
```

Check here for more info: [read user input](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)

Comment: `read -p "Enter your name, followed by [Enter]: "` would suffice.

Comment: True, condensed is always better, great suggestion @mbratch