# Shell user prompt (Y/n)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I just wanted to write a small sript for copying some files for my NAS,
so I'm not very experienced in Shell-Scripting.
I know that many command line tools on Linux use the following sheme for Yes/No inputs

```
Are you yure [Y/n]
```

where the capitalized letter indicates the standard action which would also be started
by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Which is nice for a quick usage.

I also want to implement something like this, but I have some trouble with caching the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
Here is what I got so far:

```
read -p "Are you sure? [Y/n] " response

    case $response in [yY][eE][sS]|[yY]|[jJ]|[#insert ENTER codition here#]) 

        echo
        echo files will be moved
        echo
        ;;
    *)
        echo
        echo canceld
        echo
        ;;
esac
```

I can add what ever I want but it just won't work with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick solution:

```
read -p "Are you sure? [Y/n] " response

case $response in [yY][eE][sS]|[yY]|[jJ]|'') 

    echo
    echo files will be moved
    echo
    ;;
    *)
    echo
    echo canceled
    echo
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: In each case statement you have two `echo`'s to add new line. Every one can be removed and replaced with an `echo` after `read` and after `esac` to achieve the same result. That would shorten your script by two lines.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `bash` 4, you can "pre-seed" the response with the default answer, so that you don't have to treat `ENTER` explicitly. (You can also standardize the case of `response` to simplify the `case` statement.

```
read -p "Are you sure? [Y/n] " -ei "y" response
response=${response,,}  # convert to lowercase
case $response in
    y|ye|yes)
      echo
      echo files will be moved
      echo
    ;;
    *)
      echo
      echo cancelled
      echo
      ;;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `read -n1`

```
read -n1 -p "Are you sure? [Y/n] " response

case "$response" in 
   [yY]) echo "files will be moved";;
   ?) echo "canceled";;
esac
```

As per `help read`:

```
  -n nchars return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting
        for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than NCHARS
        characters are read before the delimiter
```

Comment: well that is one option, okay.
But however is there another way to do like I described?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you want to know as your question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 4):

This has input validation that accepts "Y", "y", "an empty string" or "n" and "N"  as valid input for the question [Y/n].

```
#!/bin/bash

while : ; do # colon is built into bash; and is always true. 
    read -n1 -p "Are you sure? [Y/n] " response
    echo 
    case "$response" in
        y|Y|"") echo "files will be moved"; break ;; # Break out of while loop
        n|N) echo -e "canceled"; break ;; # Break out of while loop
        *) echo "Invalid option given." ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you gave option [y/n], the code can be changed something like (edited):

```
#!/bin/bash

 while true
 do
   echo "Are you sure? [Y/n]?"
    read response
    case $(echo ${response:-Y}|tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') in
        Y|YES)
            echo "files will be moved!"
            break
            ;;
        N|NO)
            echo "aborted!"
            exit
            ;;
        *)
            echo "incorrect selection!"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: What happens here if the user enters "yes"?

Comment: OP asked [Y/n] but other "yes" entries can be handled like -
 
y|Y|YES|yes|Yes)

Comment: And your answer would be more useful if you show that. The OP handles that in the question, you should too.

Comment: @glenn jackman, I agree. I see much better answers listed already in this thread. Anyway I edited with another approach instead of giving all possible combinations of "y" or "yes".

Comment: That's better, but you're not actually meeting the requirement: if the user just hits enter, that's the same as answering "Y"

Comment: Made a slight modification in the code to capture "enter" as "Y". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few years passed since the question was asked, but since it's still relevant in searches I thought I'd provide the different method I ended up using.

I wanted to lock the question in place until a y/n/enter is pressed and without spamming the prompt request, so I (ab)used the `-s` echo suppression and came up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Confirm action [y/N]? "
while true; do
    read -sn1 response
    case "$response" in
        [yY]) echo 'y'; break;;
        [nN]|"") echo 'n'; exit 0;;
    esac
done
```

Upon N or Enter the script is ended, otherwise it just goes on as intended. The additional echos to output user choice is not necessary, but I left it in as a visual feedback.

Also, by moving the `|""` around, you can default the enter key to either yes or no responses.

Comment: changing the first `echo` to `echo -n` is even better.

Comment: It slipped when I transcribed it to SO, thanks for noticing.