# Bash script to prompt for a location of where to create a folder

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Is it possible for a shell script to prompt a user of where to create a directory?

```
echo -n "Enter folder path location::::"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while read -ep "Enter folder path location: " file_dir; do
    if [ -d "${file_dir}" ]; then
         echo "${file_dir} already exists - please enter a valid directory path."
    else
        mkdir -p "${file_dir}"
        break
    fi 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n 'Enter folder path location: '
read folder_path
echo "You entered $folder_path"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n "Enter folder path location::::"
read folderName
echo "$folderName is the directory name inserted"
```

You can add many controls.
I think it's better that you start reading some bash manual and books. Something like [Advanced BASH Scripting Guide.](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion to read the Advanced BASH Scripting Guide, but I don't see anything in this answer that merits a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *prompt* feature of the read, like:

```
err() {
    echo "Error: $@" >&2 ; return 1
}
while :
do
    read -r -p "Enter directory name > " newdir
    #check already exists
    [[ ! -e "$newdir" ]] || err "$newdir exists" || continue

    #if want to find real parent directory
    #real="$( cd "$(dirname "$newdir" )" && /bin/pwd -P )" || continue

    #some other safety tests here if need   

    #create a directory, if success - break the cycle
    mkdir "$newdir" && break

    #otherwire repeat the question...
done
#ok
```