# Bash Script to let user choose from a list or enter their own

Tags: bash, variables, case-statement

I have a simple script which i want to list some pre-filled choices or for the user to enter a number to correlate with a build

This is what I have currently.

```
read -p "Please select from the list below or enter the build number you would like to download " build
    case {build} in
        Latest)
            build=lastSuccessful
            break;;
        *)
            break;;
    esac
```

The problem is that is doesn't provide a list for the user to choose.

Ideally it would look something like this

Build Choices
1) Latest      3) Successful    5) pick a build number (1-10000)
2) Stable      4) etc.
Please select from the list above or enter the build number you would like to download: _

Or would it be better to do this in 2 case statements? Asking if they want to choose a particular build or enter their own.

UPDATE: After some thinking I ended up simplifying it to a yes no statement

```
while true;do
    read -p "Would you like to download the latest successful build? (yes/no) " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]*)
            echo
            build=lastSuccessfulBuild
            break;;
        [Nn]*)
            echo
            read -p "Enter the build number to download: " build
            break;;
        *) echo 'I am not going to tell you again';;
        [Qq]*) exit 0;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Print the list before the `read` statement, and then say `list above`.

Comment: what part of `select area in area1 area2 area3` in the answer you accepted don't you understand ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377618/how-do-i-create-a-shell-script-with-multiple-choice-menu-variables) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `select` statement might be what you want:

```
select name in Latest Successful  Stable "Pick a Build Number" ;
do
  case "$name" in
        Latest)
            build=lastSuccessful
            break
          ;;
        Successful)
            build=lastSuccessful
            break
          ;;
        Stable)
            build=lastSuccessful
            break
            ;;
        Pick*)
            read -p "Enter a number from 1 to 10000: " number
            break
            ;;
  esac
done
```

This generates the menu:

```
1) Latest
2) Successful
3) Stable
4) Pick a Build Number
#?
```

The user can enter 1, 2, or 3 and the variable `name` is set to the corresponding string.

Comment: But this will limit the options the user can chose wont it? I want them to be able to select a number as well and that number can range from 1-10000

Comment: @krodami OK.  I added the option of entering a number.

Answer (score 0):

You may like `dialog` as well.

Chceck this out:

```
dialog --no-cancel --menu "Please select from the list below or enter the build number you would like to download " 11 60 12 1 Latest 2 Successful 3 Stable
```