# script sh : command wait an input from keyboard, but script type the input

Tags: bash, ksh

I've a command that needs input from keyboard and cannot get it directly from command line, like *sudo*, and I've forgotten the syntax to pass a known variable to a 'terminal input: [sudo] password for cl-r:'

```
#/bin/bash (or ksh)
.....
VARIABLE_NEEDED=$1
mycommand_wait_and_needs_input_from_keyboard [?? magic-instruction_beginning ??] # command prompt for input
VARIABLE_NEEDED
[?? magic-instruction_end ??]
# ... command executed
[ $? != 0 ] && ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

Comment: @m.s. I've modified my answer : It not a read problem from a script, but to pass an instruction to a waiting command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean the following:

```
echo -n "$VARIABLE_NEEDED" | mycommand_wait_and_needs_input_from_keyboard
```

Comment: It's a right way to pass input data to another command (`-n` is optionnal). When you say "it does not work", what's happening exactly please?

Comment: I tried with sudo `echo -n mypass | sudo -i` and I got 
`[sudo] password for cl-r :` and not the root prompt.

Comment: Ok... Due to security reasons, there's no way (to my knowledge) to enter a `sudo` password with a bash command. You can tweak `sudo` in many ways, see `man sudo`, but not pass the password with the help of a variable.

Comment: I'm confuse, I've forgotten that it is done by an *expect script* I used many years ago before using Java fork possiblities. Cf. : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect . Undirectly you help me to solve my problem ! :)

Comment: Expect tutorial and Autoexpect tool : http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [line 7 of my dotfiles](https://github.com/AJ-Acevedo/dotfiles/blob/master/init/osx-defaults-mavericks.sh#L21). You can invoke `sudo -v` in a bash script to run it with sudo permissions.

Comment: Interesting, but my problem is keybord configuration at launch time is not the keyboard I usually use, so special characters are not on the key face : *QWERTY* vs *AZERTY* vs *enhanced* and so on...