# how user can respond to system prompts using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to automate something using shell script.

My question is when there is a system prompt, for e.g. "Do you want to continue (y/n):"
And I need to input y using my shell script, how can it be done ? So at the end when the system prompt displays on the shell then my shell script should be automatically able to enter y.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a duplicate: [How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/226703/1848245)

Answer (score 0):

You can try an [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script

> It is used to automate control of interactive applications such as
>   telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck, rlogin, tip, ssh, and others. Expect uses
>   pseudo terminals (Unix) or emulates a console (Windows), starts the
>   target program, and then communicates with it, just as a human would,
>   via the terminal or console interface.

Answer (score 0):

It is really quite easy using redirection, and there are several ways to do it.  This uses a *here string*.  First to generate that system prompt:

```
more one.sh
read -p "Do you want to continue (y/n): " ans
echo "Answer was $ans"
```

Now the script to run the program:

```
bash one.sh <<< 'y'
```

Output:

```
Answer was y
```

Warning!  This works by redirecting the process's standard input stream.  Some programs, particularly when getting passwords, access the terminal driver at a low level for security reasons.