# Create interrupt in bash by keys like ENTER Or ESC

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to know is it possible to interrupt a bash script using keys like `ESC` or `ENTER`? By sending `SIGINT /CTRL + C` I am able to do, but due to some reasons(Check note in the last line) I cannot use `CTRL +C`. So I need to have some custom way to cause an interrupt.

In other terms: In following script, `cleanup` function is called when `CTRL + C` is pressed. Now need to modify this behavior so that `cleanup` function should be called when some keys like `ENTER` OR `ESC` is pressed.

```
cleanup() {

#do cleanup and exit
echo "Cleaning up..."
exit;

}
echo "Please enter your input:"
read input

    while true
        do
          echo "This is some other info MERGED with user input in loop + $input"
          sleep 2;
          echo "[Press CTRL C to exit...]"
          trap 'cleanup'  SIGINT
        done
```

## Query:

1. Is it possible to use custom keys for causing interrupts in bash?
2. If possible, how to achieve it?

## Note:

Reason: This script is called from another C++ program which has its own trap handling. So the trap handling of this script is conflicting with the parent program and ultimately the terminal is getting hung.  In my organization that program's code is frozen so I cannot change its behavior. I have to tweak this child script only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a *dirty trick* which is doing my work just fine. `read` and `case` statement options are the key. Here I am timing out `read` command so that while true continues unless `esc` or `enter` is pressed.

```
cleanup() {

#do cleanup and exit
echo "Cleaning up..."
exit;

}

exitFunction()

{
echo "Exit function has been called..."
exit 0;
}
mainFunction()
{
    while true
        do
          echo "This is some other info MERGED with user input in loop"
          IFS=''
          read -s -N 1 -t 2 -p  "Press ESC TO EXIT or ENTER for cleanup" input
          case $input in
                $'\x0a' ) cleanup; break;;
                $'\e'   ) exitFunction;break;;
                      * ) main;break;;
          esac
        done
}

mainFunction
```

Comment: `$'\e'` matches not only ESC, also at least arrows and function keys.

Answer (score 1):

Following works ^M for ENTER and ^[ for ESC but may

```
stty intr ^M 
stty intr ^[
```

but after cannot use ENTER
to restore default

```
stty intr ^C
```

After comment, as the shell is interactive what about asking to continue instead using trap, also clean can be done in special EXIT trap.

[How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

or yet another solution using select

```
echo "Do you want to continue?"
PS3="Your choice: "

select number in Y N;
do
    case $REPLY in
    "N")
        echo "Exiting."
        exit
        ;;
    "Y")
        break
        ;;
    esac
done
# continue
```