# How to debug this distro dector in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a distribution checker for an installer but am getting errors that I can not figure out. Would someone help with this distribution checker - am I doing the variable declaration wrong here? The script gives me the errors:

> read: `NAME=Fedora': not a valid identifier and blank.

Is there any other way I could achieve the same thing without uname? I'll check uname after I have fixed this so that I can have the installer work on mac as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#distribution detection system
NAME=$(head -n 1; grep NAME= "/etc/os-release")


#installer promt
read -p "Install tools [y/n]?" insatll_base
case "$insatll_base" in 
y|Y ) echo "installing addtional programs and tools";

#checks for fedora
read $NAME;
if [$NAME="Fedora"]; then 
dnf install cpan -y;
cpan install Menu::Item;
fi;

read $NAME;
if [$NAME="NAME=Redhat"]; then 
dnf install cpan -y;
cpan install Menu::Item;
fi;
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Following that, you should *validate* `/etc/os-release` exists before calling `grep` (or more properly `sed`) and setting `NAME` and then *validate* `$NAME` is non-empty. (e.g. `unset NAME; if test -r "/etc/os-release"; then NAME=$(sed -n 's/^NAME=["]\([^"]*\)["]/\1/p' /etc/os-release); fi; test -n "$NAME" || { echo "error: no NAME"; exit 1; }`)

Comment: it fixed the errors but does not do what i want it to (check your Distribution

Comment: okay but i don't know if it exists that what the first check is for is it finds the fist line "NAME=" in the file then it prints the distribution name, then if it fails it would go on to try uname (yet to implement that). and why sed i'm only looking for a pattern called NAME= also wouldn't awk be able to do that as well? but i will give that a go thanks

Comment: Try running simply `sed -n 's/^NAME=["]\([^"]*\)["]/\1/p' /etc/os-release` to confirm its functionality. Since I `unset NAME` before the `if` block, you simply check `test -n $NAME` after to confirm it is filled, otherwise handle the error.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so what does the ["]\{^"] .../p  mean I apologise if I'm asking a dumb question but I've never used sed before.

Comment: `sed -n` suppresses normal output, `["]\([^"] .../p` anything enclosed in `[xy]` is a *character class* meaning "*made up of the specified chars*" (unless preceded by a *circumflex* `'^'` which means "*NOT made up of the specified chars*"). The `p` at the end means `print` (overriding the `-n` for lines that match). So putting it together, the entire expression says find lines beginning with `NAME="` then capture (e.g. between `\(...\)`) everything not a `"` up to the next `"` and replace everything (using a *back reference*) with what was captured, and then print. `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin right thanks so there blank char references so that anything between the start point specified and end of the line is put into a variable then that arable is printed

Comment: Yep, you got it. It's just a lot cleaner than a double call of `grep` and `head` and gives you more control over removing the actual double-quotes present in `/etc/os-release`. (you can use `egrep` to do it all it one as well). Understand that `grep` is actually `sed`'s little brother (a subset of `sed`).  Another way is to simply `source /etc/os-release` and then you can use `$NAME` directly (but I don't like sourcing files with a lot of unneeded information)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin cool thanks I will see if it works in the morning (I love it when my laptop dies) but yeah I'll give that a go. Also could I pipe the fail into an other test say something along the lines of uname -s then importing that into a variable. Because surely I can use try statements as a result of other try statements.

Comment: Yes, if the `test -n "$NAME"` fails, you can go to `uname` and also some distros use, e.g. `/etc/arch-release`, `/etc/SuSE-release`, but those are largely historical.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so would it be worth including or not really anymore!

Comment: You can check for the existence of more than `/etc/os-release` and then act on each with something like `array=( /etc/*-release ); if [ "${#a[@]}" -gt '1' ]; then for f in "${a[@]}"; do ...handle each...; done; fi`. You will also need to check that they are not just empty files. `/etc/arch-release` is simply an empty file, so it won't help, but older SuSE distros used `SuSE-release` to actually contain the information and did not have an `os-release`.

Comment: It might help to have a look at the `bash` util [`neofetch`](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch), since it detects Linux distros...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so also if the OS-release fails then do checks on those files. Except for arch-release. I'll have to think of a way of doing that but if that test fails then I'll do unmade -s to get the kernel name to see if it's Darwin or BSD rather then Linux.

Comment: @agc I will look into it

Comment: This isn't a proper [mcve], which focuses only on **a single problem**, removing code unrelated to that issue -- there are a whole bunch of separate problems here. Please fix what [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net/) finds, and ask *tightly-focused* (individual!) questions on any remaining problems, if those remaining problems don't have solutions already (which they almost assuredly will).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it did not work the variable just prints a empty line and that's it. and now the script gives me a error:    line 30: read: `': not a valid identifier

Comment: The `...` means you fill in the code to handle each, like `case "$f" in 'os-release' ) printf "found os-release\n";; *SuSE* ) printf "found %s\n" "$f";; esac`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so I can case inside of a case?

Comment: `case` begins the *case statement*, `esac` (case  backwards) ends it. Like `if ... fi`. See: [**Using case statements**](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html)

Comment: Yeah I know but I didn't know you case inside of an existing case statement unless you mean case it before the promt case

Comment: @mattmods Re "*case inside of a case?*": `case` statements can be nested as many as might be needed.   It's seldom necessary however.

Comment: @agc oh I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

- There's no need to use `head` or `grep` for `/etc/os-release`.  Just put a `.` before it, and all its variables are loaded.
- When two `then ... fi` blocks contain the same code, there's no need for two `if` statements.
- [Myrddin Emrys' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/226724/6136214) to [How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script/226724#226724) provides a good minimal example of how to use `case`.

Here is one way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#distribution detection system
if [ -s /etc/os-release ] ; then
    . /etc/os-release

    #installer prompt
    read -p "Install tools [y/n]?" yn
    if [ "${yn,,}" = y ] ; then
         echo "Installing additional programs and tools...";

         #checks for Fedora or Redhat
         case "$NAME" in
              Fedora|Redhat)  dnf install cpan -y
                              cpan install Menu::Item ;;
         esac
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Okay so would I just add more case statements or would I do it in the same case?

Comment: @mattmods, Please, use the **correct** terms.   The *correct* term for `Fedora|Redhat)` is a "pattern", and what  comes after, from `dnf` to `::Item` is a "command list".   And *yes* you can add more patterns and lists.  These must go after the previous `;;` and before the `esac`.

Comment: okay thank you. and for the no option would you just add an other if statement with the y changed to n. also can you add a if statement that runs if the first one fails so that it finds arch-release and Suse-release, then put that into a varable so that it can run on suse and arch?

Comment: @mattmods, No you wouldn't do it that way... an `elseif` (for the "*n*") and an additional `case` *pattern* would be much better.  The virtue of having a `case` statement is to simplify such nests of `if`s.

Comment: but I still want it to install the programs if you enter n  just not install all additional stuff. Or would it not matter about the pattern?

Comment: @mattmods, Suppose there's only *two* possibilities: 'true' and 'false'.  And 'true' runs 'ABC' then runs 'DEF', but 'false' runs only 'DEF'.  All that's needed to handle *both* cases is this code:  `if true ; then ABC ; fi ; DEF`, which can be simplified to `true && ABC ; DEF`.  For only *two* simple possibilities a `case` statement is a bit of a waste.

Comment: so your saying just use && instead of a separate case?

Comment: @mattmods, Sometimes...  compare `read -p "Enter [y/n]?" yn ; case $yn in y) echo "yes" ;; n) echo "no" ;; *) echo "that's not y/n" ;; esac` with `read -p "Enter [y/n]?" yn ; if [ "$yn" = y ] ; then echo "yes" ; elif [ "$yn" = n ] ; echo "no" ; else echo "that's not y/n" ; fi`.  Both do the same thing, but the `case` is shorter.  Such code assumes _three_ possible answers, {*yes,no,neither*}, but sometimes it's just {*yes,no*}, and sometimes there's no additional action for *no* -- in *those* cases, `read -p "Enter [y/n]?" yn ; [ "$yn" = y ] && echo "yes"` is enough.