# Bash Script Not Working. Does anyone know why?

Tags: bash, syntax

I wrote this code in a bash script. When I run it, the prompt, "Start? [y/n]", but no matter what I respond, it just closes the window. Also, what is the proper syntax for an if statement.

```
@echo off
set /p choice="Start? [y/n] "
echo $choice
echo $choice$
if $choice$ == "y"
then 
goto Labelyes
fi

if $choice$ == "n"
then
exit
fi

:Labelyes
echo YAY
set /p goodbye="BYE"
if [1==1]; then exit; fi
```

Thank You!

Comment: That's not `bash`, for starters. It looks more like a DOS batch script.

Comment: Use the "read" command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script

Comment: Take a basic Bash tutorial, lots around, just type "bash tutorial" into your search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, the syntax you have used is more like a Microsoft Windows batch (`.bat`) file than anything else.  Below is a conversion to bash.  To look at the syntax for read, type `help read`.

The syntax for an `if` statement (read `man bash` or [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html)) is confusing at first.  The `[[` is actually a *command* which does pattern matching, and a simple example is shown.  The pattern can only be on the right of the `=`.  Note that `==` can also be used but the standard says to use `=`.

Simple tests can also use the `test` command, or `[`.  Arithmetic tests use `((`.

`goto` is a four-letter word and not used in polite circles (some disagree).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#set /p choice="Start? [y/n] "
read -p "Start? [y/n] " choice

echo "$choice"
#echo $choice$

if [[ $choice = [Yy]* ]]   # Accepts y, Y, yes, Yup, etc...
then
    #goto Labelyes
    echo YAY               # Quotes are optional, but beware embedded whitespace
    #set /p goodbye="BYE"
    read -p "BYE" goodbye

elif [[ $choice == "n" ]]  # Only n   "elif" means "else if"
then
    exit
else
    # What happens if neither Y nor N were given?
    echo "Invalid response, exiting anyway"
fi

#I have no idea what this is supposed to be for
#if [1==1]; then exit; fi
```

You could use a `case` statement instead, but get the `if` statement understood before trying that.

Answer (score 0):

[Bash if statement](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-if-statements.php)

Your script is generally incorrect so thinking about why it doesn't work does not make sense.