# Where do I put the actual command when it comes to Y/N confirmation?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script) and found it useful for a script I am trying to write, but where do I put the code to execute if the proper input is given.

My code is as such:

```
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to install this program?" yn 
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) make install; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) echo "Yes or No";; 
    esac 
done
```

Now the code i am trying to execute (with confirmation) is:

```
apt-get install vsftpd
```

So where does that code actually go? I might just be dumb when it comes to this, but I cannot figure this out.

Comment: use a process of elimination. Does it make sense to execute the `N` branch and `exit`? What is left? Or do you need to search for a tutorial that includes a `case ... esac` example? There should be many out there, or search here `[bash] esac` would probably be enough. Good luck.

Comment: Replace `make install` with whichever command you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @that other guy and @Charles Duffy, i fixed my script by making the script code as follows:

```
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to install $program-name?: " yn 
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo "some code here"; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Yes or No";; 
     esac 
done
```

Replace `$program-name` with whatever, and `$code` with the code you want confirmation for.

Comment: Or you could put the code *after* the loop, not inside it at all.

Comment: No, I mean after the `done`, so outside the loop altogether -- which is where flow control will jump after `break` is executed.

Comment: where does exit go then?

Comment: `exit` stops the script entirely; it doesn't go *anywhere*.

Comment: oh, so if i want the script to keep going, i would use `break` in the `[Nn]` line?

Comment: Correct; if you don't want the script to exit immediately, you shouldn't use `exit`.

Comment: BTW, insofar as `$code` implies that you actually have some code in a variable, [doing that is a Very Bad Idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).