# Linux shell get device id from user input

Tags: linux, shell, lsusb

I am working on an install script for a program that needs the device id from lsusb in it's configuration so I was thinking of doing the following:

```
$usblist=(lsusb)
#put the list into a array for each line.
#use the array to give the user a selection list usinging whiptail.
#from that line strip out the device id and vender id from the selected line.
```

Sorry I haven't gotten very far with my code but I am stuck on this and have no idea how to do what I would like to do. Please can someone help. I am very new to shell scripting

Comment: have you tried to ask on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)? since that one really bound to the OS (Linux)

Comment: No I have not. Will need to wait 40 min before I can repost. I just have no idea even how to ask the question properly so that people can understand what I am trying to do

Comment: I have been looking into using sed but can't seam to figure out how to take a line that looks like this: "Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0665:5161 Cypress Semiconductor USB
to Serial" and removing only this:  "0665:5161"

Comment: have you tried `grep`? it support regex if i remember correctly..

Answer (score 3):

#### Using `whiptail` for choosing USB device

For preparing `whiptail` or `dialog` command, with *USB ID* as *TAG* and *description* as *item*, you could create a little sub-shell:

```
read usbdev < <(
    declare -a array=()
    while read foo{,,,,} id dsc;do
        array+=($id "$dsc")
      done < <(lsusb)
    whiptail --menu 'Select USB device' 20 76 12 "${array[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty
)
```

Nota:

- The `$array` variable won't exist outside of the scope of subshell.
- As `$array` is populated by `($id "$dsc")` and used by `"${array[@]}"`, space in description won't break item list.
- syntax `read foo{,,,} id dsc` will read output of `lsub` by line, space separated, dropping 5 first words, assigning 6th word to `id` and rest of line to `dsc`.

This could render something like:

[image]

Then

```
echo $usbdev 
1d6b:0002
```

You could find more sample using `whiptail`, `dialog` and other ways at [How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script/27875395#27875395)
and [USB removable storage selector: USBKeyChooser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119759/removable-usb-stick-listed-as-non-removable-in-sys-block/119816#119816)

Comment: I've already posted an [usbKeyChooser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119816/27653) for listing only *removable USB storage*, at march 15, 2014...

Answer (score 1):

To extract the device IDs from `lsusb`, the following line can be used:

```
lsusb | awk '{ print $6 }'
```

If you need to store the IDs within an array, use the line below:

```
mapfile -t device_ids < <(lsusb | awk '{ print $6 }')
```

Accessing the first element in the `device_ids` array: `echo ${device_ids[0]}`