# How to create a list of option and selecting it using arrow key in shell

Tags: shell

I need to create a list of option and allow the user to choose from the list using an arrow key, just like how we select the presets when creating a vue project
[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27875395/1765658), there are several ways and tools. (Try the demo!!)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `dialogue` utility will help you. It lets you build a menu with options that looks like this, given the following command:

```
dialog --checklist "Choose toppings:" 10 40 3 \
    1 Cheese on \
    2 "Tomato Sauce" on \
    3 Anchovies off
```

This example is a multi-select, but there is a radio-select option too.
[image: Example dialogue]

This page provides examples and a greater description than I ever could:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807

I refer to it any time I want to build an interactive options in a script; maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find solutions for this on Stack and different sources on the web and came up with nothing, so I built one on my own. This solution provides exact GUI based selection menu for Bash built purely in Bash.

[image]

You can alter things like indicator and colors using the variables and replacing with ASCII codes.

```bash
function MENU() {
  YELLOW="\033[1;33m"
  NC="\033[0m"
  INDICATOR="<"
  SELECTED=0
  OPTIONS=($@)
  LENGTH=$#

  PRINT_MENU() {
    clear

    for (( i=0;i<(($LENGTH));i++ ))
    do
      if [[ $SELECTED -eq $i ]]
      then
        echo -e "${OPTIONS[$i]} $YELLOW$INDICATOR$NC"
      else
        echo ${OPTIONS[$i]}
      fi
    done
  }

  PRINT_MENU

  while read -rsn1 input
  do
    case $input in
      "A")
        if [[ $SELECTED -lt 1 ]]
        then
          SELECTED=$(($LENGTH-1))
        else
          SELECTED=$(($SELECTED-1))
        fi
        PRINT_MENU
       ;;
      "B")
        if [[ $SELECTED -gt $(($LENGTH-2)) ]]
        then
          SELECTED=0
        else
          SELECTED=$(($SELECTED+1))
        fi
        PRINT_MENU
       ;;
      "") return $(($SELECTED+1)) ;;
    esac
  done
}
```

**How to use?**

```bash
OPTIONS=('test' 'test' 'test')
MENU ${ARR[@]}
RESULT=$?

echo $RESULT
```

Answer (score -5):

From what I understand you want something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Script with selection

PS3='What would you like for breakfast? '
menu=("Bacon and Eggs" "PB&J Sandwich" "Cereal" "Quit")
select option in "${menu[@]}"
do
    case $option in
        "Bacon and Eggs")
            echo "Option 1 selected"
            ;;
        "PB&J Sandwich")
            echo "Option 2 selected"
            ;;
        "Cereal")
            echo "Option 3 selected"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

You can check it out by saving it as menu.sh and run by

> sh menu.sh

Comment: but this wont allow the user to select the option using arrow key right?

Comment: yes. you are right