# Capturing results of dialog call embedded in a bash function

Tags: bash, dialog

I want to call the unix `dialog` editbox from within a generic function in bash. The two outcomes I am interested in are:

1. If the user hits OK I would like to capture what the user has entered into the editbox
2. Detect if the user hits Cancel

Here is some code I have but I'm not sure if this is the best way:

```
function ib_generic()
{
    tmp_file="/tmp/file.tmp"
    if [ -f $tmp_file ]
    then
    rm -f $tmp_file
    fi
    
    mkfifo $tmp_file

    # push the user input to $tmp_file
    dialog --stdout \
    --title "$1" \
    --backtitle  "My Backtitle" \
    --inputbox "$2" 20 40 2> $tmp_file &

    # detect 'cancel' or 'escape':
    if [[ $? -eq 0 || $? -eq 255 ]] 
    then
        rm -f $tmp_file
        echo 1
    else # 'ok' was pressed so proceed:
        result="$( cat /tmp/file.tmp )"
        rm -f $tmp_file
        echo $result
    fi
}
```

What's the best way to cancel the result if OK is hit and if not, how to detect Cancel or Escape?

Comment: Don't run `dialog` in the background. The script won't wait for it to exit.

Comment: Just use `result=$(dialog ...)`

Comment: @Barmar I've updated the question. I want to find the best way to detect output if OK is hit or if not, if Cancel is hit.

Comment: The variable assignment will set `$?` based on how they exited the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog returns different exit codes on each button, here's how i'd do it:

```
input=$(
    dialog --stdout \
           --title "test" \
           --backtitle  "My Backtitle" \
           --inputbox "$2" 20 40 
)

case $? in
     0) echo "ok $input";;
     1) echo 'cancel'   ;;
     2) echo 'help'     ;;
     3) echo 'extra'    ;;
   255) echo 'esc'      ;;
esac
```

More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926381/bash-script-exit-codes-for-dialog-menu)

Answer (score 1):

Don't run `dialog` in the background, since it won't wait for it to finish and won't set `$?`.

You also have the exit statuses wrong. `0` means `OK` was pressed, `1` means `Cancel`, and `255` means `Escape`.

```
dialog --stdout \
    --title "$1" \
    --backtitle  "My Backtitle" \
    --inputbox "$2" 20 40 2> "$tmp_file"

exit=$?
if [ $exit -eq 0 ] # OK was pressed
then
    echo "$result"
elif [ $exit -eq 1 ] || [ $exit -eq 255 ] # Cancel or Escape was pressed
then
    echo 1
else
    echo 2
fi
```

There's a fuller example [here](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php)