# If statements accepting yes or no in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to accept user input of yes or no to a question and depending on the answer read back the value of my variable. I can never get commands attached to variables to work or my if statements to accept yes or no. It just keeps going to "not a valid answer".
Please let me know how to actually get those to work in bash script. I keep lookingup different things to try and nothing seems to work. 
Here is what I have now:

```
yesdebug='echo "Will run in debug mode"'

nodebug='echo "Will not run in debug mode"'

echo "Would you like to run script in debug mode? (yes or no)"

read yesorno

if [$yesorno == 'yes']; then
        $yesdebug

elif [$yesorno == 'no']; then
        $nodebug

else
        echo "Not a valid answer."
        exit 1

fi
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/226703/3220113

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. Failure to put spaces around `[` (which is a command name) and `]` (which is a mandatory but functionless argument to `]`).
2. Treating the contents of a variable as a command; use functions instead.

---

```
yesdebug () { echo "Will run in debug mode"; }

nodebug () { echo "Will not run in debug mode"; }

echo "Would you like to run script in debug mode? (yes or no)"

read yesorno

if [ "$yesorno" = yes ]; then
    yesdebug

elif [ "$yesorno" = no ]; then
    nodebug
else
    echo "Not a valid answer."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Offtopic: OP might be helped with a `debug()` function that only echoes something when `"$yesorno" == yes`.