# bash: while loop fails to exit when condition is met

Tags: bash, boolean-logic

I'm new to bash, and the below while loop is driving me crazy. I want the loop to exit when the user enters y or n but it fails to do so. I have tried different ways but no luck. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

```sh
    echo "want to go for a walk Y/N "
    read answer
    while [ "$answer" != "y" ]  ||  [ "$answer" != "n" ]  ; do 
               
        echo "Enter y or n"
        read answer
    done
```

The second solution also is in the same scenario

```sh
    echo "want to go for a walk Y/N "
    read answer
    while [ "$answer" != "y"   ||   "$answer" != "n" ]  ; do 
               
        echo "Enter y or n"
        read answer
    done
```

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

Answer (score 2):

Of course it won't exit. That loop never will.

In your code, `answer` is always NOT 'y' OR NOT 'n' (together, at the same time).

It is so because if you select 'y' then it's NOT 'n' and if you select 'n' then it's NOT 'y'.

If you have `TRUE || FALSE = TRUE`
And if you have `FALSE || TRUE = TRUE`, so the loop keeps going.

The condition you want to use is `&&` (AND), so while `answer` is NOT 'y' AND NOT 'n' then go on, but if it is one of them then exit.

`TRUE && FALSE => FALSE` and `FALSE && TRUE => FALSE` and that's what you need for the loop to finally end.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "want to go for a walk y/n "
read -r answer
while [ "$answer" != "y" ]  &&  [ "$answer" != "n" ]  ; do 
           
    echo "Enter y or n"
    read -r answer
done
```

The `-r` flag in `read -r var` is to avoid reading backslash as an escape character. It is not relevant for this toy problem but it is a best practice to include it.

Comment from David: Keep in mind that the code doesn't handle case, so Y is not recognized as y.

Comment: You will also never match `'Y'` or `'N'` checking for `'y'` and `'n'` `:)`

Comment: But of course! Good catch! I made it more explicit.

Comment: Other alternatives would be: `while ! [ "$answer" = "y" ] || [ "$answer" = "n" ]` or `until [ "$answer" = "y" ] || [ "$answer" = "n" ]`

Comment: Correct. I tried to change as little as possible to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Or something truly ugly: `printf "go for a walk (y/n)? "; while read -r answer && [ "$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "${answer:0:1}")" != 'y' -a "$(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< "${answer:0:1}")" != 'n' ]; do printf "go for a walk (y/n)? "; done; echo "answer: $answer"` which handles case conversion for you as well `:)`

Comment: `until  [[ ${answer::1} =~ [YyNn] ]] ; do ...` will match any input that starts with  [YyNn]. If we want only single char answer condition, will be `[[ #${#answer} = 1 &&  $answer =~ [YyNn] ]]`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg `[[ #${#answer} = 1 && $answer =~ [YyNn] ]]` is not correct. Should be `[[ ${#answer} -eq 1 && $answer =~ [YyNn] ]]` and may be simplified to `[[ $answer =~ ^[YyNn]$ ]]`

Comment: You can convert the answer to lowercase inside your check with `${answer,,}`

Comment: @WalterA it's worth noting that the syntax `${answer,,}` is Bash 4.0 and can be subject to portability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget in a `while` loop, the first commands list may also contain multiple statements:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "want to go for a walk y/n "

while
  read -r answer
  case $answer in
    [yYnN]) false ;;
  esac
do
  echo "Enter y or n"
done
```

Or using `until` and Bash's **E**xtended **R**egular **E**xpression:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "want to go for a walk y/n "

until
  read -r answer
  [[ $answer =~ [yYnN] ]]
do
  echo "Enter y or n"
done
```

And a featured, case-insensitive POSIX compatible implementation:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "want to go for a walk y/n "

until
  read -r answer
  case $answer in
    [yY])
      echo "Handling Yes answer stuffs"
      ;;
    [nN])
      echo "Stuffs for No answer"
      ;;
    *)      # Landing here if invalid answer
      false # Proceed with the do...done statements
      ;;
  esac
do
  echo "Enter y or n"
done
```

Comment: great set of answers. I'd use `while true; do ... break; done` for (arguably) more robust alternative