# Bash Yes No Prompt asking again

Tags: bash

My first bash script; working well except for this line:

```
# MAINTENANCE MODE ON
while true; do
read -p "TURN ON MAINTENANCE? (Y/N)" yn
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) sudo /root/Nginx-Maintenance-Mode/maintenance.sh example.com on;;
    [Nn]* ) break;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
esac
done
```

This works but after running the command it is asking me the same question again; I don't know why.

Comment: you need `break` after your command in `yY` section, else while "`true`" will keep looping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `break` after your command like so:

```
# MAINTENANCE MODE ON
while true; do
read -p "TURN ON MAINTENANCE? (Y/N)" yn
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) sudo /root/Nginx-Maintenance-Mode/maintenance.sh example.com on; break;;
    [Nn]* ) break;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have put your statements of `read`, `switch`  and your script/command is present in a `while` loop which will run so it will be keep running until/unless you place a break inside your yes condition. So kindly do add the same and it should work then.

May be you are looking for following.

```
cat script.ksh    
while true; do
read -p "TURN ON MAINTENANCE? (Y/N)" yn
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) echo "Entered yes here..."
            ;&
    [Nn]* ) echo "You entered no here..."
            break;;
    * )     echo "Please answer yes or no."
esac
done
```

Lets see how it runs and goes:

```
./script.ksh
TURN ON MAINTENANCE? (Y/N)test
Please answer yes or no.
TURN ON MAINTENANCE? (Y/N)no
You entered no here...
```

Comment: In this case, since the OP's `[Nn]` branch is basically a no-op, you can use `;&` to "fall through" to that case from `[Yy]`, rather than duplicate the `break`.

Comment: @chepner, sure, thank you sir added it now, I hope I did it fine, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to loosen your requirement to enter an explicit no. `Y` or `y` will turn on maintenance mode. *Any* other response, whether `N` or a seemingly invalid response, will do nothing.

```
# MAINTENANCE MODE ON
read -p "TURN ON MAINTENANCE? (Y/N)" yn
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) sudo /root/Nginx-Maintenance-Mode/maintenance.sh example.com on;;
esac
```