# How to accept 'yes' from shell script "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" using ssh. Without using StrictHostKeyChecking=no

Tags: shell, dropbear

I'm using ssh command to remotely executing a shell script with -o **StrictHostKeyChecking=no ** option to bypass the authentification:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP '/test-script'
```

However, I'm using a sh shell that does not support the StrictHostKeyChecking=no option:

```
root:~ Jeff$ ssh StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP '/test-script'

Could not create directory '/home/root/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host '192.168.186.1 (192.168.186.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:KOx9T7VeRy9dJ2ug+tfnlbnG/7Fm0I5Tl/ziTkE4JaE.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

All the -o option for ssh I have are:

```
ssh -o help
ssh: Available options:
ExitOnForwardFailure
UseSyslog
```

So is there any way I can prompt the 'yes' for the 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?' question on the remote host?

I tried the following options but none of them worked

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP '/test-script' | yes
yes | ssh StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP '/test-script'
yes yes | ssh StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP '/test-script'
```

Is there any way I can run the ssh remote command, read the prompt and find this question 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?' and just enter yes?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`?

Comment: As I mentioned. I'm using a customized sh shell, that does not have ```-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no```. So sorry I can't use it :(

Comment: `StrictHostKeyChecking` is part of ssh, not sh! And I thought, you were missing `-o`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I meant to type ```-o``` but I forgot in the question. I will fix it

Comment: `yes yes`? Very yes.

Comment: `ssh -o help
ssh: Available options:
 ExitOnForwardFailure
 UseSyslog`
These are all my avaliable options

Comment: Ok, this looks like dropbear's ssh client.

Comment: C tag? Why? Tag removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming this is dropbear's ssh client.

From [`man dbclient`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dbclient)

> **-y**
> Always accept hostkeys if they are unknown. If a hostkey mismatch occurs the connection will abort as normal.

This should be the dropbear equivalent to `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.

Comment: WOW! It works great! Thank you! Did not know this spell

Comment: @DavidKanes @Olaf it means if we edit in shell script to `ssh -y StrictHostKeyChecking=no` then prompt will not come at the time of debug/execute, isn't it?

Comment: @ShahinP No, these are two options from different ssh iplementations. `-y` belongs to dropbear, and `StrictHostKeyChecking` is from openssh. So it depends on which ssh you use. If it is openssh, use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, but if you have dropbear ssh client, you must use `-y`

Comment: @OlafDietsche In my script `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` has not been mentioned but still i am getting prompt as yes/no when debug/run the shell script.

Answer (score 4):

Try `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new`. From the [OpenSSH documentation on `StrictHostKeyChecking`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#StrictHostKeyChecking):

> If this flag is set to **accept-new** then ssh will automatically add new host keys to the user's known_hosts file, but will not permit connections to hosts with changed host keys.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new root@$IP '/test-script'
```