# If var == "yes" in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I am new to bash and I found out a command called `cal` in a bash tutorial and want to test it with if

here is the code:

```
    echo "What is your name?"
read PERSON
echo "Hello, $PERSON"
echo "Do you want to know the date?"
read CALENDAR
if [[ CALENDAR == "yes" ]]; then
  cal
else
  echo "Bye"
fi
```

so can you help me? when I run it shows :

```
 bash main.sh
What is your name?
Tony #I input
Hello, Tony
Do you want to know the date?
yes #Also I input this
Bye
```

And I'm also new I don't know bash but I know Python so don't tell me if I used python in bash

PLEASE help me run it. You can run this if you want in [Replit](https://replit.com/@Yoplayer1py/Test#main.sh)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/226703/3220113 for more inspiration.

Comment: @Yoplayer1: In your code, you are testing whethr the string `CALENDAR` is equal to the string `yes`, and this will of course fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
echo "What is your name?"
read PERSON
echo "Hello, $PERSON"
echo "Do you want to know the date?"
read CALENDAR
if [[ $CALENDAR == "yes" ]]; then
  cal
else
  echo "Bye"
fi
```

It should be `if $var == "yes"`

Comment: Put a `$` before CALENDAR on line 6.

Comment: `$CALENDAR` should be quoted.

Comment: @stark not necessary

Comment: Try it with `yes please`

Comment: @stark the if statement says yes. when I enter yes please it doesn't work. lol.

Comment: @stark what means by calendar should be quoted