# Linux Shell Script: Encrypting password in Linux Shell Script (.sh)? is it possible

Tags: linux, bash, shell, password-encryption

i wonder if it is possible to "hide" the password in Linux Shell Script?
for example, i have a code here

```
echo “Enter Password:"
read p
 
if [ $p = “Passwords" ]
then
    echo “Password Granted"
else
    echo "Password Denied"
fi
```

as you can see  when im going to bash it at Linux Terminal, i will be asked to type/enter the password in line 2. in Linux Terminal, whatever you type, the characters are visible. if i type "passwords" or "passhwords" or any character, i can see visibly each character/letter of what i type there.

i wonder if it is possible to "hide" it? similar to Facebook or Google account login where when i type any character it will appear as "*****" instead of the actual characters.
is there a code i should enter before "read p"(2nd line) so whatever i will type will be hidden?

OS: Ubuntu

Comment: Are you asking how to encrypt the password after they enter it, or how to hide their typing?

Comment: ahh i think i used the wrong term. my really bad(i edited the post). im asking how to "hide" the password/text im entering when typing
like in Google Account or Facebook login where the password text bot shows "********" when entering characters.

Comment: see `read -s` or `dialog --passwordbox`.

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27875395/1765658), section about *Some tricks for dedicated tools*

Comment: i see that. i found the answer. thank you!