# Store Gum Input in variable?

Tags: bash, input, terminal

I use a package named [Gum](https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum) to beautify my software (terminal app). So, it's a mini-shell where when I type "help" it outputs the list of commands. But, for that, I need to store the user input of the Gum input. See source code below.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Customize Console
# set-title FBD

echo "Undertale Jokes, that's all. Mainly. You know, as ya want."

while true
  do 

    #Input
    PRT=$(gum input > history.txt --placeholder " Enter Command")

    # Logic
    if PRT=="list"; then
        echo "exit"
        echo "list"
        echo "rules"
    fi
    if PRT=="exit"; then
        exit
    fi
    if PRT=="rules"; then
        echo "There is not much rules but :\n
        1. Be silly and trolly
        2. Don't insult or any things like that
        3. Always have a Sans sticker in your desktop wallpaper
        4. Chew gum while using the software
        5. Every Arch user shoulds ay "I use Arch, BTW" every day on the chat.\n"
    fi

done
```

For now, when I exec the software, I have the gum input, but ... See a how it actually works :

```
Undertale Jokes, that's all. Mainly. You know, as ya want.
exit
list
rules
```

I typed rules

Comment: Have a look at [How do I prompt for Yes/No/Cancel input in a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script/27875395#27875395). You may have to redirect STDIN and/ot STDOUT!

Comment: Consider first running your script through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) to clean out many of the common mistakes in your script like `if PRT=="list"`